# Convert MM:SS string to HH:MM:SS in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I have this piece of code which works nicely to convert HH:MM:SS to seconds as an integer.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < nrdaily.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
      double NRT = TimeSpan.Parse(nrdaily.Rows[i][3].ToString()).TotalSeconds;
      nrdaily.Rows[i][3] = NRT;
  }
```

However, I have a CSV file I'm dealing with where a field has many values that are stored in MM:SS format and TotalSeconds seems to misinterpret it as HH:MM and gives a false result.

How could I check the string to see if it's in HH:MM:SS format, and if it is in MM:SS convert it to HH:MM:SS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the string length for starters to identify the format.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nrdaily.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     string time = nrdaily.Rows[i][3].ToString();
     if (time.Length == 5)
          time = "00:" + time;
     double NRT = TimeSpan.Parse(time).TotalSeconds;
     nrdaily.Rows[i][3] = NRT;
}
```

Checking length is a very simplistic approach. To identify the format more accurately, you could use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [TimeSpan.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example:

```
var testString = "01:05";
TimeSpan.ParseExact(testString, "mm\\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TotalSeconds; 
//TotalSeconds will be 65
```